# Fork() with multiple children and with waiting for all of them to finish

Tags: c, fork

I want to create a program in C, where I use fork() to create multiple children, then wait for all of them to finish and do parent code (only once).
I tried using for loop and two forks but I there is a problem: either parent code isn't running at the end or children are not running parallel.

```
//Number of processes I want to create
int processes = 6;

pid_t *main_fork = fork();

    if(main_fork ==0){

      for(int i=0;i<processes;i++){
        pid_t *child_fork = fork();

        if(child_fork ==0){

           // child code
           exit(0);
        }
       else if(child_fork >0){
        //And here is the problem, with the wait: children don't 
        //run parallel and if I delete it, the main parent code doesn't run 
         wait(NULL);
       }else{
        // Child fork failed
         printf("fork() failed!\n");
         return 1;
       }
      }
    }else if(main_fork >0){

      wait(NULL);
      //Main parent code - here I want to do something only once after all 
      //children are done

    }else{
      // Main fork failed
      printf("fork() failed!\n");
      return 1;
    }
```

If somebody could could fix my code, or write a better solution to this problem  I would be so grateful!

Comment: `pid_t *main_fork = fork();` ?!?!

Comment: `fork` returns a pid_t, not a pointer to a pid_t

Comment: Why are you creating multiple children from the first child?  Instead, the loop that creates children should be in the parent, who will create all the children and then wait for all of them.  (But not waiting for any until after it has created them all.)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the children to run in parallel, you have to do the wait after all the children has been started. Otherwise you start a child, wait for it to finish, start a new one, wait for that to finish, start a third one, wait for the third one to finish,  and so on...

So what you typically want to do is to start all the children and put all the `pid_t` in an array, and when you are finished you may call `wait()` for each `pid_t`

This is the simple, and good enough solution for your case.

Here is a sample code that you can fit to your problem:

```
pid_t children[processes];

for(int i=0; i<processes; i++)
  {
    pid_t child = fork();

    if(child == 0)
      {
        // child code
         ....
        // We call _exit() rather than exit() since we don't want to clean up
        // data structures inherited from parent
        _exit(0);
      }
    else if (child == -1)
      {
         // Child fork failed
         fprintf(stderr, "myprog: fork failed, %s", strerror(errno));

         // Do real cleanup on failure is to complicated for this example, so we
         // just exit           
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    children[i] = child;
  }
// Do something if you want to do something before you expect the children to exit
.... 

for(int i=0; i<processes; i++)
  {
    pid_t child = children[i];

    int status;
    waitpid(child, &status, );

    // Do something with status
 }
```

Naturally this is not a complete example that fits any situation. Sometimes you have to tell the children when they should exit. Other times the children are not started/stopped in one go, and you have to play with asynchronous events, and so on...

Comment: Thank you for the answer and nice explanation, it works as I wanted it to work :)